# Is there a red or similar-looking moss that will grow on a stone statue?

Tags: plant-recommendations, landscaping, moss, liverworts

I'd like to try growing some moss on a stone statue.  As it's of a dragon (and I'm Welsh) it really like it to be red-ish, at least in parts.

Any advise on a red moss, or some other plant that I could use?

Answer (score 4):

There is a red lichen, but as far as I'm aware, lichens are not something you'd be able to buy, and even if you could, you can't just attach it in some way. The usual method is to paint the statue with live yoghurt, keep it somewhere shady and wait and  see which mosses/lichens start to grow. Lichens which grow on something rich in iron or copper tend to be more red in colour than on stone.

Comment: I wonder if I ground a couple of iron pills into the yogurt if that might attract the reader lichens?

Comment: @BanksySan pass, no idea, worth the experiment though,I'd have thought!

Comment: This is for your bathroom mat?  Any plant you want to color needs LIGHT.  Even if a plant can survive in low light situations and that means yours unless you've got REAL grow lights, will be pale, especially the purple and reds.  Gee, I'd rather have a wall hanging where those plants can be catered to with light, moisture and taken down to fertilize once in a while.  Brought down to be used for bare footsies while sitting on your couch?  Plants that aren't normally endowed with purple or red coloring will never become other than green.  Or gray.

Comment: @stormy, erm, I dunno what you've been reading, but the question is about growing something red coloured on a stone statue outdoors...  no idea where you got bathroom mat from?!

Comment: Oh shoot.  This is the OP with the moss question, just recently.  BanksySan has ordered a bunch of different mosses to make this very cool bath mat.  Seriously.  Sounds yummy but she doesn't have the list of names of the mosses she is getting (he?) and has been told growing moss as a bathroom mat is easy, mosses are HARDY.  She hasn't chosen the medium yet...unless this is a different project just go to the most recent questions and she is asking what the different species of moss this person is standing upon on this mat she wants to reproduce...

Comment: @stormy I think you'll find its a separate subject in a separate question... you could always delete your comment under here... but at least it sort of explains why you introduced the subject of bath mats, which really had me very puzzled indeed...

Comment: It looks like she/he is now considering a different moss project.  Same OP.  I sent her a link of a huge lion in moss with mexican feather grass for a mane!  I love moss but in no way are they hardy indoors and if the environment ain't perfect for moss, good grief.  I am glad she/he is considering another project for moss.

Comment: When I get feedback from you I am scrambling!!  My environment isn't as quiet as yours or I am just a big airhead!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49259/discussion-between-bamboo-and-stormy).

Answer (score 0):

Sphagnum capillifolium is a red moss.

Comment: True. But not a type of moss that would grow on a stone statue.

Comment: @Stephie I was about to ask that.  Pity, because it looks very striking.